# Run function in parallel in async workflow?

Tags: f#

The following code

```
let doWork n = async {
    [1..5]
    |> Seq.iter(fun i ->
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 1000 // Simulate working
        printfn "%s runs %i seconds" n i
        )
}

let f1 = async {
    do! doWork "f1"
    return 1
}

async {
    let a = f1
    do! doWork "main"
    let! i = a
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

And it prints the following result. It shows that the two `doWork` calls run sequentially.

```
main runs 1 seconds
main runs 2 seconds
main runs 3 seconds
main runs 4 seconds
main runs 5 seconds
f1 runs 1 seconds
f1 runs 2 seconds
f1 runs 3 seconds
f1 runs 4 seconds
f1 runs 5 seconds
```

However, I want the `doWork` called by `f1` and the main code be running in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
let computation () = async {
  printfn "Start work"
  do! Async.Sleep(100)
  printfn "Finished work"
}

let s = seq {
  for i in 1 .. 10 do
    let c = computation()
    yield c
}

s |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore |> Async.Start
```

`Async.Parallel` converts the `Async<unit> list` to `Async<unit []>` which can be run in parallel then.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that simply putting `Async.Parallel |>` before the `Async.RunSynchronously` would work fine also.

Comment: If you're refering to the original question's code, I'd say no... `Async.Parallel`'s signature is `seq<Async<'T>> -> Async<'T []>`. It cannot parallelize a single async, only a sequence of asyncs.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right.  Somehow I had misread the code and thought that there were  multiple `async`s joined up.